# Почему одно и тоже меню на разных страницах отображается по-разному?

Tags: javascript, tilda

Есть сайт https://ninjamail.ai/
Сделан на тильде.
На всех страницах, стоит одно и тоже меню (header).
И только на одной странице, оно отображаеся некорректно.
Вот она: https://ninjamail.ai/why-ninjamail
А именно, пункты меню не чисто чёрные, а серые.
Плюс не работает hover. При наведении нет подчёркивания. Хотя повторюсь меню одно на всех страницах.

Comment: Сравните результирующие стили, вероятно что-то чем-то перекрывается

Answer (score 0):

Потому что на той странице все 3 пункта меню активные и применяется стиль `t-active`, т.к. все пункты указывают на этот адрес.

Comment: Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Нужно сделать так, чтобы ссылки меню указывали на разные (нужные) страницы, например `/why-ninjamail-1`, `/why-ninjamail-2`, `/why-ninjamail-3`. Подробнее есть в [документации](https://help-ru.tilda.cc/menu) Тильды